# Scroll ListView on Button click

Tags: android, listview

I have developed an app in which i'm using horizontal `ListView` for display content(Actually this content works for header).I have used two buttons for scroll right and left to see more content.I'm confused about this,Can any suggest me how to solve this problem ? **Thanks**

**Code of HorizontalListView**

```
public class HorizontialListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

    public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
    protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
    protected int mCurrentX;
    protected int mNextX;
    private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
    protected Scroller mScroller;
    private GestureDetector mGesture;
    private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
    private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
    private boolean mDataChanged = false;

    public HorizontialListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    private synchronized void initView() {
        mLeftViewIndex = -1;
        mRightViewIndex = 0;
        mDisplayOffset = 0;
        mCurrentX = 0;
        mNextX = 0;
        mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
        mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        mOnItemSelected = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClicked = listener;
    }

    private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            synchronized (HorizontialListView.this) {
                mDataChanged = true;
            }
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            reset();
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();
        }

    };

    @Override
    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
        // TODO: implement
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        }
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        reset();
    }

    private synchronized void reset() {
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        // TODO: implement
    }

    private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
        LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
        if (params == null) {
            params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        }

        addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
        child.measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top,
            int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mDataChanged) {
            int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
            initView();
            removeAllViewsInLayout();
            mNextX = oldCurrentX;
            mDataChanged = false;
        }

        if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
            mNextX = scrollx;
        }

        if (mNextX < 0) {
            mNextX = 0;
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        }
        if (mNextX > mMaxX) {
            mNextX = mMaxX;
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        }

        int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

        removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
        fillList(dx);
        positionItems(dx);

        mCurrentX = mNextX;

        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    requestLayout();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void fillList(final int dx) {
        int edge = 0;
        View child = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        if (child != null) {
            edge = child.getRight();
        }
        fillListRight(edge, dx);

        edge = 0;
        child = getChildAt(0);
        if (child != null) {
            edge = child.getLeft();
        }
        fillListLeft(edge, dx);

    }

    private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
        while (rightEdge + dx < getWidth()
                && mRightViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

            View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex,
                    mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
            rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

            if (mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount() - 1) {
                mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
            }
            mRightViewIndex++;
        }

    }

    private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
        while (leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
            View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex,
                    mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
            leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
            mLeftViewIndex--;
            mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
    }

    private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        while (child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
            mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
            mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
            removeViewInLayout(child);
            mLeftViewIndex++;
            child = getChildAt(0);

        }

        child = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        while (child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
            mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
            removeViewInLayout(child);
            mRightViewIndex--;
            child = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        }
    }

    private void positionItems(final int dx) {
        if (getChildCount() > 0) {
            mDisplayOffset += dx;
            int left = mDisplayOffset;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth,
                        child.getMeasuredHeight());
                left += childWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
        mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean handled = mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return handled;
    }

    protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        synchronized (HorizontialListView.this) {
            mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int) -velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }

    protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        return true;
    }

    private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return HorizontialListView.this.onDown(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return HorizontialListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX,
                    velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            synchronized (HorizontialListView.this) {
                mNextX += (int) distanceX;
            }
            requestLayout();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Rect viewRect = new Rect();
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                int left = child.getLeft();
                int right = child.getRight();
                int top = child.getTop();
                int bottom = child.getBottom();
                viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
                if (viewRect.contains((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY())) {
                    if (mOnItemClicked != null) {
                        mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontialListView.this,
                                child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i,
                                mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
                    }
                    if (mOnItemSelected != null) {
                        mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(
                                HorizontialListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex
                                        + 1 + i,
                                mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

    };

}
```

**Xml Code**

```
<com.ui.HorizontialListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightcorv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftcorv" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Horizontal ListView" ?

Comment: Default listview is vertical .I have customized it and made this horizontal for my requirement

Comment: Is it not simpler to use a Gallery ?

Comment: hey check the code below. It works in vertical listview, hope works for your requirement also.

Comment: u have used @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        // TODO: implement
    }
So may be becoz of this my code is not working

Comment: yeah may be but can u tell me what should i use here

Comment: just delete this code and let the default happen

Answer (score 2):

```
private void startScroll(AbsListView view)
{
    try
    {
        Field field = android.widget.AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFlingRunnable");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object flingRunnable = field.get(view);
        if (flingRunnable != null)
        {
            Method method = Class.forName("android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable").getDeclaredMethod("endFling");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(flingRunnable);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}

Just call startScroll(myListView); when you need to start scroll.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, this may help you.

```
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View view = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();

// restore
mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the setSelection() method instead of scrolling the list by 100 pixels each time. Increment the selection when you're scrolling down and decrement it while scrolling up. This will assure that the right item is being clicked. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @GooGLE, can u elaborate with example

Answer (score 0):

For previous, refer BtnPrev and for next refer btnNext
R.id.lv is id of your list view.

```
Button btnPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

            int firstVisibleItem = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int lastVisibleCount = lv.getLastVisiblePosition();
            if (firstVisibleItem != 0) {
                int count1 = firstVisibleItem
                        - (lastVisibleCount - firstVisibleItem);
                if (count1 < 0) {
                    lv.setSelection(0);
                }

                else {
                    lv.setSelection(count1);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            int count = lv.getCount();
            int firstVisibleItem = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int lastVisibleCount = lv.getLastVisiblePosition();
            if (lastVisibleCount != count) {
                int count1 = lastVisibleCount
                        + (lastVisibleCount - firstVisibleItem);
                if (count1 > count) {
                    lv.setSelection(count);
                } else {
                    lv.setSelection(count1);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Hitesh for reply but its not working.Have look my code ,I'm using this for HorizontalListView

Comment: Can u post ur code for horizontal list view(xml and java code you used to customise)

Comment: in ur code, dont override setSelection and try the code again

Comment: i din't understand your meaning